# python script to create another python script (or python executable)

Tags: python-2.7

As part of my code, I want to write a python method which when called, creates an executable file. (Another script that I can execute with python's interpreter is also fine).

This final script is almost fixed, except for a few input objects that only my method knows about, and which are necessary for the final executable to work (a dictionary for example). How can I link these objects to the final executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a work for some templating engine. [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize/deserialize (save/load) the data which the other executables would use.